# kubectl diff fails on AKS

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, azure-aks

I'd like to diff a Kubernetes YAML template against the actual deployed ressources. This should be possible using [kubectl diff](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#diff). However, on my Kubernetes cluster in Azure, I get the following error:

```
Error from server (InternalError): Internal error occurred: admission webhook "aks-webhook-admission-controller.azmk8s.io" does not support dry run
```

Is there something I can enable on AKS to let this work or is there some other way of achieving the diff?

Comment: What is your kubernetes version ? ( `kubectl version` )

Comment: `Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.2", GitCommit:"59603c6e503c87169aea6106f57b9f242f64df89", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-01-18T23:30:10Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14", GitVersion:"v1.14.8", GitCommit:"c52f59bbba5fbf21fbb18e9a06f96e563fe4c20a", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-01-31T20:00:26Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.10", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}`

Comment: I believe you are not allowed to change any settings of admission-controllers used by **azure** and it looks like `"aks-webhook-admission-controller.azmk8s.io"` with its current settings does not support `dry run`. I think you can always raise an issue on https://github.com/Azure/AKS related to this problem. I cannot find anything similar currently on their github page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround you can use standard GNU/Linux `diff` command in the following way:

```
diff -uN <(kubectl get pods nginx-pod -o yaml) example_pod.yaml
```

---

I know this is not a solution but just workaround but I think it still can be considered as full-fledged replacement tool.

> Thanks, but that doesn't work for me, because it's not just one pod
>   I'm interested in, it's a whole Helm release with deployment,
>   services, jobs, etc. – dploeger

But anyway you won't compare everything at once, will you ?

You can use it for any resource you like, not only for `Pods`. Just substitute `Pod` by any other resource you like.

Anyway, under the hood `kubectl diff` uses `diff command`

In `kubectl diff --help` you can read:

> KUBECTL_EXTERNAL_DIFF environment variable can be used to select your
>   own diff command. By default, the "diff" command available in your
>   path will be run with "-u" (unified diff) and "-N" (treat absent files
>   as empty) options.

---

The real problem in your case is that you cannot use for some reason `--dry-run` on your AKS Cluster, which is question to AKS users/experts. Maybe it can be enabled somehow but unfortunately I have no idea how.

Basically `kubectl diff` compares already deployed resource, which we can get by:

```
kubectl get resource-type resource-name -o yaml
```

with the result of:

```
kubectl apply -f nginx.yaml --dry-run --output yaml
```

and not with actual content of your yaml file (simple `cat nginx.yaml` would be ok for that purpose).

---

You can additionally use:

```
kubectl get all -l "app.kubernetes.io/instance=<helm_release_name>" -o yaml
```

to get `yamls` of all resources belonging to specific **helm release**.

As you can read in `man diff` it has following options:

```
   --from-file=FILE1
          compare FILE1 to all operands; FILE1 can be a directory

   --to-file=FILE2
          compare all operands to FILE2; FILE2 can be a directory
```

so we are not limited to comparing single files but also files located in specific directory. Only we can't use these two options together.

So the full `diff` command for comparing all resources belonging to specific **helm release** currently deployed on our **kubernetes cluster** with **`yaml` files from a specific directory** may look like this:

```
diff -uN <(kubectl get all -l "app.kubernetes.io/instance=<helm_release_name>" -o yaml) --to-file=directory_containing_yamls/
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work for me, because it's not just one pod I'm interested in, it's a whole Helm release with deployment, services, jobs, etc.

Comment: If I understood it correctly, `kubectl diff` will diff the contents of the given YAML file with the resources already deployed. My YAML file contains many different resource types, so testing every resource manually is not feasible.

I know, that I can script my way around this by analyzing the YAML file and then fetching the resources and diff them but I wanted to know about other possibilities.

But thanks so far!

Comment: I understand that comparing resources one by one would be very tedious task and you may rather want to avoid it. You can additionally use `kubectl get all -l "app.kubernetes.io/instance=<helm_release_name>" -o yaml` to get `yamls` of all resources belonging to specific helm release.

Comment: That’s a great idea. Could you work that into your answer? I'd like to accept it then.

Comment: Sure, I just did it.

Comment: Author of `kubectl diff` here. `kubectl diff` will run a "server dry-run" request to the server to know how the resource would have been modified, and then uses it for the right side of the diff. There's no way to simulate that without server dry-run. Server dry-run requires admission webhooks to play along, and allow these requests. I would expect Azure to fix the webhook so that it doesn't have any side-effect on dry-run requests (or update the config to say it doesn't).